# problem creating a new package with catkin_create_pkg

Tags: ros, catkin, catkin-create-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to create a new package in my workspace with `catkin_create_pkg` and I get this error:

```
afgonzalez@afgonzalez-desktop:~/ros_workspace/src$ catkin_create_pkg 
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/catkin_create_pkg", line 10, in <module>
  from catkin_pkg.package_templates import create_package_files, PackageTemplate
  
  ImportError: No module named catkin_pkg.package_templates</div>
```

I have reinstalled `ros-groovy-catkin` and `python-catkin-pkg` package but the error still there.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84051/problem-creating-a-new-package-with-catkin_create_pkg/) by [ane_fernandez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3688/ane_fernandez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-09-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-09-29**:
Please post the version number of your catkin_pkg package: python -c "import catkin_pkg; print(catkin_pkg.**version**)"

**Comment by [ane_fernandez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3688/ane_fernandez/) on 2013-09-29**:
The version of the catkin_pkg is 0.1.20

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-09-30**:
Please get the folder where catkin_pkg is in your installation ( python -c "import catkin_pkg; print(catkin_pkg.**file**)" ) and post the directory content.

**Comment by [ane_fernandez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3688/ane_fernandez/) on 2013-09-30**:
The directory content is: /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/catkin_pkg/**init**.pyc

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-10-01**:
That is pretty incomplete. Please remove remove the file and reinstall the Debian package python-catkin-pkg again.

**Comment by [ane_fernandez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3688/ane_fernandez/) on 2013-10-02**:
I have deleted **init**.pyc file and reinstalled  the python-catkin-pkg and the templates aren't found yet. The content directory is still the same: /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/catkin_pkg/**init**.pyc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like you have an out-of-date `caktin_pkg`, but since you said that you have updated recently I would guess that you're using Ubuntu and had `catkin_pkg` installed from `pip` at some point.

See:

http://answers.ros.org/question/49143/problems-with-rqt-groovy-ubuntu/?answer=49153#post-id-49153

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ane_fernandez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3688/ane_fernandez/) on 2013-09-29**:
I have followed the instructions of the link but the error is still there.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-09-30**:
That's odd, the only way this can occur is if you don't have catkin_pkg installed or you have an older version installed which is overriding the updated one (which is commonly the case with `pip` and `apt-get`). Which is what @Dirk Thomas is getting at in his above comments.